# Terraform: module outputs not being recognised as variables

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-gcp

I think just a quick sanity check, maybe my eyes are getting confused. I'm breaking a monolithic terraform file into modules.

My `main.tf` call just two modules, `gke` for the google kubernetes engine and `storage` which creates a persistent volume on the cluster created previously.

Module `gke` has an `outputs.tf` which outputs the following:

```
output "client_certificate" {
  value     = "${google_container_cluster.kube-cluster.master_auth.0.client_certificate}"
 sensitive = true
}
output "client_key" {
  value     = "${google_container_cluster.kube-cluster.master_auth.0.client_key}"
 sensitive = true
}
output "cluster_ca_certificate" {
  value     = "${google_container_cluster.kube-cluster.master_auth.0.cluster_ca_certificate}"
 sensitive = true
}
output "host" {
  value     = "${google_container_cluster.kube-cluster.endpoint}"
 sensitive = true
}
```

Then in the `main.tf` for the storage module, I have:

```
client_certificate     = "${base64decode(var.client_certificate)}"
client_key             = "${base64decode(var.client_key)}"
cluster_ca_certificate = "${base64decode(var.cluster_ca_certificate)}"
host     = "${var.host}"
```

Then in the root `main.tf` I have the following:

```
client_certificate = "${module.gke.client_certificate}"
client_key = "${module.gke.client_key}"
cluster_ca_certificate = "${module.gke.cluster_ca_certificate}"
host = "${module.gke.host}"
```

From what I see, it looks right. The values for the certs, key and host variables should be outputted from the `gke` module by `outputs.tf`, picked up by `main.tf` of root, and then delivered to `storage` as a regular variable.

Have I got it the wrong way around? Or am I just going crazy, something doesn't seem right.

I get questioned about the variable not being filled when I run a plan.

EDIT:

Adding some additional information including my code.

If I manually add dummy entries for the variables it's asking for I get the following error:

```
Macbook: $ terraform plan
var.client_certificate
  Enter a value: 1

var.client_key
  Enter a value: 2

var.cluster_ca_certificate
  Enter a value: 3

var.host
  Enter a value: 4
...
(filtered out usual text)
...
 * module.storage.data.google_container_cluster.kube-cluster: 1 error(s) occurred:

* module.storage.data.google_container_cluster.kube-cluster: data.google_container_cluster.kube-cluster: project: required field is not set
```

It looks like it's complaining that the data.google_container_cluster resource needs the project attribute. But it doesn't it's not a valid resource. It is for the provider, but it's filled out for provider.

Code below:

Folder structure:

```
root-folder/
├── gke/
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── outputs.tf
│   ├── variables.tf
├── storage/
│   ├── main.tf
│   └── variables.tf
├── main.tf
├── staging.json
├── terraform.tfvars
└── variables.tf
```

root-folder/gke/main.tf:

```
provider "google" {
  credentials = "${file("staging.json")}"
  project     = "${var.project}"
  region      = "${var.region}"
  zone        = "${var.zone}"
}

resource "google_container_cluster" "kube-cluster" {
  name               = "kube-cluster"
  description        = "kube-cluster"
  zone               = "europe-west2-a"
  initial_node_count = "2"
  enable_kubernetes_alpha = "false"
  enable_legacy_abac = "true"

  master_auth {
    username = "${var.username}"
    password = "${var.password}"
  }

  node_config {
    machine_type = "n1-standard-2"
    disk_size_gb = "20"
    oauth_scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring"
    ]
  }
}
```

root-folder/gke/outputs.tf:

```
output "client_certificate" {
  value     = "${google_container_cluster.kube-cluster.master_auth.0.client_certificate}"
 sensitive = true
}
output "client_key" {
  value     = "${google_container_cluster.kube-cluster.master_auth.0.client_key}"
 sensitive = true
}
output "cluster_ca_certificate" {
  value     = "${google_container_cluster.kube-cluster.master_auth.0.cluster_ca_certificate}"
 sensitive = true
}
output "host" {
  value     = "${google_container_cluster.kube-cluster.endpoint}"
 sensitive = true
}
```

root-folder/gke/variables.tf:

```
variable "region" {
  description = "GCP region, e.g. europe-west2"
  default = "europe-west2"
}
variable "zone" {
  description = "GCP zone, e.g. europe-west2-a (which must be in gcp_region)"
  default = "europe-west2-a"
}
variable "project" {
  description = "GCP project name"
}
variable "username" {
  description = "Default admin username"
}
variable "password" {
  description = "Default admin password"
}
```

/root-folder/storage/main.cf:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host     = "${var.host}"
  username = "${var.username}"
  password = "${var.password}"
  client_certificate     = "${base64decode(var.client_certificate)}"
  client_key             = "${base64decode(var.client_key)}"
  cluster_ca_certificate = "${base64decode(var.cluster_ca_certificate)}"
}
data "google_container_cluster" "kube-cluster" {
  name   = "${var.cluster_name}"
  zone   = "${var.zone}"
}
resource "kubernetes_storage_class" "kube-storage-class" {
  metadata {
    name = "kube-storage-class"
  }
  storage_provisioner = "kubernetes.io/gce-pd"
  parameters {
    type = "pd-standard"
  }
}
resource "kubernetes_persistent_volume_claim" "kube-claim" {
  metadata {
    name      = "kube-claim"
  }
  spec {
    access_modes       = ["ReadWriteOnce"]
    storage_class_name = "kube-storage-class"
    resources {
      requests {
        storage = "10Gi"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

/root/storage/variables.tf:

```
variable "username" {
  description = "Default admin username."
}
variable "password" {
  description = "Default admin password."
}
variable "client_certificate" {
  description = "Client certificate, output from the GKE/Provider module."
}
variable "client_key" {
  description = "Client key, output from the GKE/Provider module."
}
variable "cluster_ca_certificate" {
  description = "Cluster CA Certificate, output from the GKE/Provider module."
}
variable "cluster_name" {
  description = "Cluster name."
}
variable "zone" {
  description = "GCP Zone"
}
variable "host" {
  description = "Host endpoint, output from the GKE/Provider module."
}
```

/root-folder/main.tf:

```
module "gke" {
  source = "./gke"
  project = "${var.project}"
  region = "${var.region}"
  username = "${var.username}"
  password = "${var.password}"
}
module "storage" {
  source = "./storage"
  host = "${module.gke.host}"
  username = "${var.username}"
  password = "${var.password}"
  client_certificate = "${module.gke.client_certificate}"
  client_key = "${module.gke.client_key}"
  cluster_ca_certificate = "${module.gke.cluster_ca_certificate}"
  cluster_name = "${var.cluster_name}"
  zone = "${var.zone}"
}
```

/root-folder/variables.tf:

```
variable "project" {}
variable "region" {}
variable "username" {}
variable "password" {}
variable "gc_disk_size" {}
variable "kpv_vol_size" {}
variable "host" {}
variable "client_certificate" {}
variable "client_key" {}
variable "cluster_ca_certificate" {}
variable "cluster_name" {}
variable "zone" {}
```

I won't paste the contents of my `staging.json` and `terraform.tfvars` for obvious reasons :)

Comment: In your state and in "terraform output" do you have values ?

Comment: Unable to tell from either as it's not getting that far. As soon as I run a plan it asks for values of the variables. I've put dummy values in, but I have other errors following that which I need to resolve. I see nothing in output and tfstate never populates.

Comment: Was more of a sanity check to make sure it's all the correct way around. Maybe it's the other issues causing it?

Comment: From what you've explained, I think it makes sense, but there's something we're missing by not seeing all of the code and all of the error messages.

Comment: Apologies, I see that it's difficult to help with limited information. I've updated the original post with the error I get at the moment along with all of the code and the folder structure. Hopefully that will help. Thanks for looking, I appreciate it.

Comment: Sometimes things just make more sense when you write them out... I suppose the issue is that I have `data "google_container_cluster" "kube-cluster" {}` in a separate place to `resource "google_container_cluster" "kube-cluster" {}` <-- makes sense, however... would I now need to output those values to make them available for the storage module?

Comment: @jonnybinthemix - i see you've declared the `data "google_container_cluster" "kube-cluster"` resource, but I don't see where in that module that you use it. Try removing that and re-testing.

Comment: @KJH - I see.. not sure why that's the case. I was previously having an issue creating the persistent volume.. and I was advised to add the data part in there.. but now I remember I changed the way I was doing it. That seems to get rid of the final error, however it's still not recognising the outputs.. and so it's asking me to complete the variables for the certs and key when I start the plan. `Jons-MacBook-Pro$ terraform plan
var.client_certificate
  Enter a value: 1

var.client_key
  Enter a value: 2

var.cluster_ca_certificate
  Enter a value: 3

var.host
  Enter a value: 4`

Comment: If I enter dummy values, it gets past the previous error. However, I don't see why it thinks those values are not populated. I haven't had a successful apply so I don't have a state, and as such I can't check with output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `/root-folder/variables.tf`, delete the following entries:

```
variable "host" {}
variable "client_certificate" {}
variable "client_key" {}
variable "cluster_ca_certificate" {}
```

Those are not variables per se that the Terraform code at the root level needs. Instead, they are being passed as 1 module's output --> input to the 2nd module.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the understanding and for the answer. That's nailed it.